# Can I add special characters to the default Android keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

Sometimes I need to type a special character or symbol that is not accessible by default through the Android keyboard. Currently I do this by copy/pasting them from other sources, very inconvenient.

Is there a way to add custom characters to the keyboard?

It's typically things like currency symbols (such as ₭ ₩ ฿ ƒ) or math symbols (such as ∈ ⇔ ∫ ⌊ ⌋ ∑ ) etc.

Comment: Maybe these are helpful: [Is There A Keyboard Layout Creator for Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52516/16575) / [How do I add another keyboard layout to my ICS phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/37999/16575)

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot add custom keys on the default Android Keyboard.

But what might work is keyboard shortcuts. You can create shortcuts like when you type "yt" option to change to "You there" will appear. So may be you can create keyboard shortcut that when you type "ms1" it will change to ₭.

To create keyboard shortcut:

- Go to  Settings -> Language & Input ->Personal dictionary
- Tap the “+” sign in the top-right corner of the screen and create your shortcut.
- Now, go to the Messaging app, compose a new message, and tap one of your new shortcuts—and when you do, the phrase you entered will appear in the row of auto-correct options just above the keyboard. Tap the phrase to add it to your message.

More details on keyboard shortcut is here: http://heresthethingblog.com/2012/12/04/androidiphone-tip-create-custom/

Answer (score 0):

For math symbols, I downloaded a Greek language keyboard, and so far it seems to do the trick. I'm using Swiftkey, but it should probably work for the Android keyboard.